# Animated .gif in Android

Tags: android, animated-gif

I've been following this tutorial:

http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/15/tutorial-how-to-play-animated-gifs-in-android-%E2%80%93-part-2/

It explains how to add an animated .gif to an `Activity`. But it doesn't explain how to add the .gif to an existing `ImageView` within an `Activity`. Is there an easy way to pull this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android Native API, ImageView does not support animated image or .GIF file. The alternate way to show animated image are follows:

1. Use VideoView
2. Use ImageView and Split the gif file into several parts and then apply animation to it

Comment: That was the original plan, but a tutorial from the same site showed that this method can be buggy and display invalid images. Maybe best to wait until Android supports .gifs.